# How to add chainload binary entry to GRUB2 boot menu?

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, which came with `memtest86+ v5` that does not support UEFI.

I'm trying to install `memtest86+ v6` on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I downloaded its binary [here](https://www.memtest.org/download/v6.20/mt86plus_6.20.binaries.zip).

I moved `memtest64.efi` to the EFI partition and added the following to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

```
menuentry 'Memtest86+ v6' {
  insmod part_gpt
  insmod fat
  set root='hd0,gpt1'
  chainloader (\$root)/EFI/memtest64.efi
}
```

Then ran `update-grub`. The entry showed on boot menu, but when I enter it:

`Error: No Server is Specified`

From GRUB console, I'm certain that `hd0,gpt1` is the EFI partition.

Alternatively, I want GRUB to boot Memtest86+ from /boot folder, but I have no idea how to make GRUB find `/boot`.

```
******@Ubuntu-Portable:~$ sudo lsblk -o +fstype
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS            FSTYPE
sda           8:0    0 953.9G  0 disk                        
├─sda1        8:1    0   476M  0 part /boot/efi              vfat
├─sda2        8:2    0   250G  0 part /                      ext4
└─sda3        8:3    0 703.4G  0 part /media/****/****       exfat
sr0          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom                         
nvme0n1     259:0    0   128G  0 disk                        
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   200M  0 part                        vfat
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   128M  0 part                        
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 127.7G  0 part                        ntfs
```

**Update:** this worked, but I still don't know how to boot from /boot instead of booting from efi partition.

```
menuentry 'Memtest86+ v6' {
  insmod part_gpt
  insmod fat
  insmod chain
  set root=(hd0,gpt1)
  chainloader /EFI/memtest64.efi
}
```

To keep things neat, I'd prefer everything done inside `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

Comment: Can you enter interactive command mode (c on the menu selection) and verify the paths? `set root=(hd0,gpt1)` (note the different syntax) followed by `ls /EFI/memtest64.efi` could give insights.

Comment: @Hermann it returned ``memtest64.efi``

Comment: In interactive mode, can you `chainload` and `boot` this way?

Comment: Your `/boot` is either a separate filesystem or part of your Linux root filesystem - which one is it? And which filesystem type is it (`ext4`, `xfs`, or something else)? The output of `lsblk -o +fstype` would be very helpful to see.

Comment: @telcoM, Linux root, but please note that there might be multiple storage devices with Linux installed on them in the boot environment. If the storage device that host the GRUB is always hd0, then the Linux root is ``hd0,gpt2``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to place your `memtest64.efi` to `/boot` instead of the EFI System Partition, something like this might do the job:

```
menuentry 'Memtest86+ v6' {
  insmod part_gpt
  insmod ext2
  insmod chain
  set root=(hd0,gpt2)
  chainloader /boot/memtest64.efi
}
```

But as you noted in the comments, this relies on the fact that the storage device is assumed to be `(hd0)`.

When booting BIOS-style, this used to be a good assumption, because on BIOS (`i386-pc`) architecture version of GRUB, the storage device identifiers like `(hd0)` normally map directly to BIOS INT 13h disk numbers. In other words, `(hd0)` refers to disk 0x80.

On BIOS, the only reliable and compatible way to specify the disk to boot from was to rearrange the BIOS disk list to make the desired boot disk be disk 0x80 (and so disk `(hd0)` for GRUB), so that's what most BIOSes do when you select the disk to boot from; so in effect, on BIOS systems, although there is no universal way to be 100% sure which disk GRUB was started from, `(hd0)` is a very, very good guess that is almost always correct.

**With UEFI, this can no longer be relied on.** While some UEFI implementations *may* do the same, the UEFI systems I personally own *don't*, and the systems I've seen at work as a sysadmin generally don't seem to do that either.

So, instead of `set root=(hd0,<partition ID>)`, you should use the `search` command of GRUB.

You could just search for a file in a known path (starting the pathname from *the root of the filesystem the file is in*, which might or might not be the Linux root filesystem):

```
search --no-floppy --file --set root /boot/memtest64.efi
```

Or you could find the UUID of the filesystem in question, and search for it, like most modern versions of `grub[2]-mkconfig` now do by default:

```
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set root 12345678-9abc-def0-1234-56789abcdef0
```

The `--no-floppy` tells GRUB to skip trying to search a floppy disk drive, and `--set root` causes the `search` command to set the `root` variable to point to the filesystem that satisfied the search condition.

So in a nutshell: use `lsblk -o +uuid` to find the UUID of the filesystem that contains the directory the `memtest64.efi` is in, then write a `40_custom` snippet like this:

```
menuentry 'Memtest86+ v6' {
  insmod part_gpt
  insmod ext2
  insmod chain
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set root <insert filesystem UUID here>
  chainloader /boot/memtest64.efi
}
```

Comment: works like charm, thanks! but why the ``ext2`` when the actual filesystem is ``ext4``?

Comment: ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem family is backwards compatible to a significant extent, and GRUB's filesystem drivers are read-only (so much simpler than write-capable filesystem drivers). A GRUB driver that was originally developed for ext2 could read ext3 as-is and needed only minor enhancements to also handle ext4 filesystems, so the driver name was not changed. As far as I know, there is no separate `ext4` filesystem module for GRUB, because the current `ext2` module actually handles all the ext2/3/4 filesystem types sufficiently for boot purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much the default GRUB file for an EFI/GPT system:

```
if loadfont unicode ; then
    set gfxmode=1024x768,800x600,auto
    set gfxpayload=800x600,1024x768
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set default=0
set timeout=-1

insmod linux
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
search --no-floppy --set=root --label "ESP"

menuentry "Start Memtest86+, use built-in support for USB keyboards" {
    linux /EFI/memtest86+/memtest keyboard=both
}
menuentry "Start Memtest86+, use BIOS legacy emulation for USB keyboards" {
    linux /EFI/memtest86+/memtest keyboard=legacy
}
menuentry "Start Memtest86+, disable SMP and memory identification" {
    linux /EFI/memtest86+/memtest nosmp nosm nobench
}
```

Comment: This is not the content of ``40_custom`` I'm afraid

Comment: This perfectly works here, so I'm afraid I cannot relate.